# undefined function sigil_I/2 (there is no such import)

Tags: elixir, rdf, elixir-mix, elixir-iex

I am working on RDFGraph using elixir.
I am running the following command on `iex`:

```
iex(1)> DC.format(~I<urn:isbn:978-1-68050-252-7>, ~L"Paper")
```

and get this error:

```
** (CompileError) iex:1: undefined function sigil_I/2 (there is no such import)
```

The function `"sigil_I"` is present in RDF git repository, which is imported in the `book` function using `import RDF.Sigils`. The `DC.format` function is present in the following file:

```
defmodule RDFGraph.Vocab do
  use RDF.Vocabulary.Namespace

  alias RDF.NS.XSD

  defvocab(DC,
    base_iri: "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/",
    file: "dc.ttl"
    # terms: ~w[
    #   contributor coverage creator date description format
    #   identifier language publisher relation rights source
    #   subject title type
    # ]
  )

  defvocab(BIBO,
    base_iri: "http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/",
    file: "bibo.ttl",
    case_violations: :ignore
  )

  defvocab(DCTERMS,
    base_iri: "http://purl.org/dc/terms/",
    file: "bibo.ttl",
    case_violations: :ignore
  )

  defvocab(EVENT,
    base_iri: "http://purl.org/NET/c4dm/event.owl#",
    file: "bibo.ttl"
  )

  defvocab(FOAF,
    base_iri: "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/",
    file: "bibo.ttl"
  )

  defvocab(PRISM,
    base_iri: "http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/1.2/basic/",
    file: "bibo.ttl"
  )

  defvocab(SCHEMA,
    base_iri: "http://schemas.talis.com/2005/address/schema#",
    file: "bibo.ttl"
  )

  defvocab(STATUS,
    base_iri: "http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/status/",
    file: "bibo.ttl",
    case_violations: :ignore
  )

  ## book function defintions

  # START:book
  def book() do

    import RDF.Sigils
    alias RDF.NS.{XSD}

    ~I<urn:isbn:978-1-68050-252-7>
    |> RDF.type(BIBO.Book)
    |> DC.creator(
      ~I<https://twitter.com/bgmarx>,
      ~I<https://twitter.com/josevalim>,
      ~I<https://twitter.com/redrapids>
    )
    |> DC.date(RDF.date("2018-03-14"))
    |> DC.format(~L"Paper")
    |> DC.identifier(~L"adopting_elixir")
    |> DC.identifier(RDF.literal("urn:isbn:978-1-68050-252-7",
        datatype: XSD.anyURI()))
    |> DC.publisher(~I<https://pragprog.com/>)
    |> DC.title(~L"Adopting Elixir"en)
  end
  # END:book

  def book_long() do

    alias RDF.NS.{XSD}

    s = RDF.iri("urn:isbn:978-1-68050-252-7")

    t0 = {s, RDF.type(), RDF.iri(BIBO.Book)}
    t1 = {s, DC.creator(), RDF.iri("https://twitter.com/bgmarx")}
    t2 = {s, DC.creator(), RDF.iri("https://twitter.com/josevalim")}
    t3 = {s, DC.creator(), RDF.iri("https://twitter.com/redrapids")}
    t4 = {s, DC.date(), RDF.literal("2018-03-14", datatype: XSD.date())}
    t5 = {s, DC.format(), RDF.literal("Paper")}
    t6 = {s, DC.identifier(), RDF.literal("adopting_elixir")}
    t7 = {s, DC.identifier(), RDF.literal("urn:isbn:978-1-68050-252-7", datatype: XSD.anyURI())}
    t8 = {s, DC.publisher(), RDF.iri("https://pragprog.com/")}
    t9 = {s, DC.title(), RDF.literal("Adopting Elixir", language: "en")}

    RDF.Description.new([t0, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9])
  end

end
```

This file is present in an RDFGraph app having the following structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnO6D.png)

The DC.format function is in rdf_graph/lib/rdf_graph/vocab.ex. This file is given above. Not sure why this function is being called and I am getting this error, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think you will have to `import` the custom sigils for them to be available inside `iex`.  `~I` is interpreted more or less as a function name, so you have to import it.  I'm not sure which repo you're using, but perhaps `import RDF.Sigils` ?

Comment: In the `book()` function, I am already importing `RDF.Sigils` but still receiving the same error. I followed this article https://medium.com/@tonyhammond/early-steps-in-elixir-and-rdf-5078a4ebfe0f and ran the GitHub code available in the article, still I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by first running `import RDF.Sigils` then `alias RDFGraph.Vocab.{DC, BIBO, DCTERMS, EVENT, FOAF, PRISM, SCHEMA,STATUS}` commands, in the `iex` command line.